# How do I embed vine in blogger responsively?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, blogger

Whenever I'm trying to embed vine on my blog, the page breaks and it doesn't adjust to the screen size. I know few lines of CSS will do the task, but actually I'm absolutely null in CSS. So please help me doing this. Thank You

Comment: body { display:none !important; }

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://embedresponsively.com. Select “Vine” and enter the video-address. It generates all the necessary code for you.

It wraps the `iframe` inside a `<div>` with the class `embed-container` and specifies the following CSS in a `<style>`-tag.

```
.embed-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.embed-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```